# Python: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python-2.7

I want to open and read all csv file in a specific folder.
I'm on OS X El Capitan version 10.11.6, and I'm using Python 2.7.10.
I have the following function in phyton file:

```
def open_csv_files(dir):
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".csv"):
            f= open(file)
            print "FILE OPEN, AND DO SOMETHING... "
            f.close
return
```

I call `open_csv_file(./dati/esempi)`

This procedure return

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sensorfile_1.csv'
```

I try to call the procedure with absolute path `/Users/Claudia/Desktop/Thesis/dati/esempi/` but I have the same error.

Moreover I define another procedure that print all filename in folder, this procedure print correctly all filenames in folder.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What happens when you do `f= open(file)` using the absolute path `/Users/Claudia/Desktop/Thesis/dati/esempi/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to build absolute path to file based on values of `root` (base dir) and file name.

```
import os


def open_csv_files(directory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file_name in files:
            if file_name.endswith(".csv"):
                full_file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
                with open(full_file_path) as fh:
                    print "Do something with", full_file_path
```